# CD-ROM has different contents for Windows and Mac

Tags: windows, mac, compact-disc

I have a old CD. When I put it in a Windows computer, the files on it are the setup executables for Windows. When I try it with a Mac, the files on it are Mac OS Classic install files (I am running Mac OS X). How do you do this and how can I access the Windows files on a Mac?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got a [multisession](http://www.pcguide.com/ref/cd/formatSession-c.html) disc. Follow the instructions [here](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20080708145453136) to mount the Windows session on OS X.